# Is there a way to make use of Jackson ObjectMapper to read the object from JSON one by one

Tags: java, json, jackson, objectmapper, jackson2

I wanted to know if it's possible to make use of `ObjectMapper` from `Jackson` to read events one-by-one.

I have a large JSON file that consists of many events that I need to convert to XML. I do not want to load the complete JSON events into my memory rather than that I want to process events one by one. Hence, I am making use of `Java Jackson` library which can traverse through the JSON file and get a single JSON event at a time which I can then convert to XML. In this way, at a time only one event will be loaded to memory.

I am aware that I can use the `JsonParser` from Jackson which will traverse through the JSON file one by one but in that way, I need to handle a lot of things.

I have the Java classes created from XSD (Using `JAXB2`) so I am thinking of using the `ObjectMapper` class from `Jackson` which can directly map each event to its corresponding Java class which later I can use to convert to the corresponding XML using the `Marshalling` method.

I am not understanding how to read the event one-by-one using `ObjectMapper` and assign it to its corresponding Java class.

Following is the simple version of my JSON file: (This is a sample JSON my original JSON is much complex)

```
{
   "@context":"https://context.org/context.jsonld",
   "isA":"SchoolManagement",
   "format":"application/ld+json",
   "schemaVersion":"2.0",
   "creationDate":"2021-04-21T10:10:09+00:00",
   "body":{
      "members":[
         {
            "isA":"student",
            "name":"ABCS",
            "class":10,
            "coaching":[
              "XSJSJ",
              "IIIRIRI"
            ],
            "dob":"1995-04-21T10:10:09+00:00"
         },
         {
            "isA":"teacher",
            "name":"ABCS",
            "department":"computer science",
            "school":{
              "name":"ABCD School"
            },
            "dob":"1995-04-21T10:10:09+00:00"
         },
         {
            "isA":"boardMember",
            "name":"ABCS",
            "board":"schoolboard",
            "dob":"1995-04-21T10:10:09+00:00"
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

I want to read the event within the "members" array one by one and check if it's "student", "teacher" etc, and then assign it to its corresponding class.

```
public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonParseException,
  JsonMappingException,
  IOException,
  JAXBException {

    final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    // Accept the Null values for some fields
    objectMapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);

    // If any unknown properties found then do not fail
    objectMapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES, false);

    //Here I want to read the element within an array 
    Student event = objectMapper.readValue(Main.class.getResourceAsStream("/events.json"), Student.class);
    System.out.println(event);

  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Im gonna tell you how to read a JSON file and get each key with his value, how to put it into a XML file will be in your hand.

**1** Create as many POJO as you need for your JSON file (You can generate it automatically here: https://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

**2** Code:

```
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
            School school = new School();
            File file = new File("school.json");
            
            //With this you map the JSON file and get the data
            try {
                school = objectMapper.readValue(file, School.class);
                
                String JSONOutputCustomer = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(school.getBody());
                System.out.println(JSONOutputCustomer);
                
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            /*With this you list the info inside of the key Body.
I just did it with body, but you can do it with any key you want, as for example Member, you can list only the information of just one member insted all of them doing the same as the example below*/

            List<Body> bodyList = new ArrayList<Body>();
            
            for(Body values : bodyList) {
                System.out.println(values.getMembers());
            }
```

Now you know how to get each key with his value.

Note: I dont put the POJO classes because are 4 and its too much code that you can get from the link i leave above

Note 2: Dont blame me for my orthography, im still learning english T_T

**Example 2**:

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
Member member = new Member();
        File file = new File("school.json");

try {
            member = objectMapper.readValue(file, Member.class);
            
            String JSONOutputCustomer = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(member);
            System.out.println(JSONOutputCustomer);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. I understood what you are trying to do here. But in this way, we are loading the entire thing in the `school` object, right? Also, our `bodyList` will have the complete list which we are traversing later. This may hamper the memory I feel that's the reason I was trying to read event-by-event where I first like to read-only `student` from the file then read `teacher` etc. `JsonParser` does this but it reads line by line which I have to map again to my Java class and objects so I am looking for something which can combine best of both (`ObjectMapper` `JsonParser`)

Comment: You are right, in this case. I will show you other case where we just read just Member only. Let me make another answer

Comment: Isnt important the List<Body> or the List<Member>, whats important is the objectMapper and what you do with it

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 there, i have modified the answer, tell me if this is what you were looking for, also, im new in stackoverflow, i dont know how to let you know that i have modified the answer or not, so i mention you in this comment, lets see if this works XD

Comment: Hi, Thanks a lot for all your efforts. Yes, I am looking into the answer and trying to modify it so that it can work with my application. I will let you know if this works or else we can figure out something. If it works out then you will have a green check next to your answer :) Thanks again have a nice day.

Answer (score 0):

Basically there are three ways to parse JSON using JACKSON2 with varying levels of difficulty.

1. ObjectMapper (mapper.readValue()): Less code to write- should be used of simple Data Binding,
2. ObjectMapper (Tree Model): Medium code - Should be used for complex JSON
3. JsonParser (Streaming Model): More code - Should be used when Ultimate performance is needed.

You are looking for Tree model.It combines the flexibility of the `JSONParser` with ease of use of `ObjectMapper`. Try the `ObjectMapper` like below

```
//create Object Node using Tree model
ObjectNode event = objectMapper.readTree("/events.json");

//Now access the Json One by One as you like
JsonNode memberNode = json.get("body").get("Members");
```

[There is Nice Mkyong tutorial for the Tree Model](https://mkyong.com/java/jackson-tree-model-example/)

To Read More:
[JACKSON2 Offical documentation](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/#3-minute-tutorial-generic-collections-tree-model)